# Linux getting rid of Carriage Return when file is being written out by intersystems cache

Tags: intersystems-cache, intersystems, intersystems-cache-studio

Working with Intersystems cache and writing a file out to a unix server and upon opening in WordPad++ the Carriage return is missing but the Line feed is still there.  Our process works in windows but for some reason not in Unix.

Answer (score 1):

You can just manually set [LineTerminator](https://docs.intersystems.com/latest/csp/documatic/%25CSP.Documatic.cls?PAGE=CLASS&LIBRARY=%25SYS&CLASSNAME=%25Stream.FileBinary#LineTerminator), which is by default for UNIX systems only $c(10)

```
set fs = ##class(%File.Character.Stream).%New()
set fs.Filename = "/tmp/somefilename"
set fs.LineTerminator = $c(13,10)
do fs.WriteLine("Text Line 1")
do fs.WriteLine("Text Line 2")
```